# Is there a way to unflag?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

I incorrectly flagged a post (simply caused by me being especially unobservant) before realizing I should have just voted-to-close (which I then did).

Is there a way for me to unflag, so I don't unnecessarily bother moderators?

Comment: None that I am aware of. Here is a similar [question on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500).

Comment: The occasional mistaken flag keeps us on our toes--it teaches us we should not automatically agree with flags posted by high-rep users (however much we might want to do that)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to unflag.

The following Stack Exchange post and some duplicated questions under the `Linked` topic in the sidebar have some pro answers/arguments toward unflagging:

[Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

There is the option of putting a bounty requesting for more attention on that topic.

---

My point of view on this is that having a misclicked flag once in a while is ok (not a big issue).